# Handle mailitem read window open event

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to trigger an event when any mailItem is opened in read window. I had created a ribbon which is for microsoft.outlook.mail.read and microsoft.outlook.mail.compose both modes. But I wish to change a label on ribbon whenever MailItem is opened in read mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similar functionality and this worked for me:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/663391b8-05ec-4a7a-85a7-136b242aa594/handling-new-email-event-or-openreplyforward-mail-event?forum=vsto

Comment: Please add some explanation. Links can disappear.